# Help in the demonstration of the theorem 1.2 chapter V from Conway's complex analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&redir_esc=y) and I'm stuck in this little detail in the demonstration of this theorem:

[image]

Why does $|\int _{T_1}g|\le \epsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

Write $T_1=\bigcup_{i=1}^3 \gamma_i$ where each $\gamma_i$ is a line segment which is a side of the triangle.  Introduce a parametrization of each $\gamma_i$ over an interval $[a,b]$ on the real line.  The integral $\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz$ is defined as $\int_a^b f(\gamma(s))\gamma'(s)\,ds$.  For a line segment, $\gamma'(s)$ is a constant $c$, and $|\int_\gamma 1\,dz|=|\int_a^b \gamma'(s)\,ds|=|c|(b-a)$ is the ordinary length, call it $l(\gamma)$, of the line segment.  For any $h(z)$ we have $$\left|\int_\gamma h(z)\,dz\right|=\left|\int_a^b h(\gamma(s))\gamma'(s)\,ds\right|=|c|\left|\int_a^b h(\gamma(s))\,ds\right|\le l(z)\cdot\max_{z\in\gamma} |h(z)|$$

We then have $$\left|\int_{T_1}g(z)\,dz\right|=\left|\sum_{i=1}^3 \int_{\gamma_i} g(z)\,dz\right|\le \sum_{i=1}^3 l(\gamma_i)\cdot(\max \{|g(z)|:z\in\gamma_i\})\le l\cdot(\epsilon/l)$$ from which the desired inequality follows.

Hopefully Conway, which I don't have handy, covers some of the statements about integrals over line segments which are made above.